# Tier prices Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2

I have got just one question, can you tell me how to change the tier prices withing the simple variants of a configurable product afterwards? I tried and saved the change in the simple variants but it is not shown on product page, there are still the "old" tier prices. 
It would be grerat if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works on Magento2:

- when you open the configurable product there are no tier prices to
  display
- after the attributes are selected to match a simple product,
  the tier prices block is not reloaded to reflect the selection
- if you add in the qty box a quantity defined as tier and add the item to
  cart, the cart price will be the right one (the one defined for the
  tier)

So, I'm afraid you have to implement an ajax tier block reloading if you want to display the tier prices on the product page in your situation.